# Splitting a string around sequences of char in Java

Tags: java, string, split

How can I split a string in Java around sequences of a character which are multiple of a particular number? Example: I have a binary string

```
101010100010000001110101110111
```

and I want to split it around sequences of zero which are multiple of 3, i.e. it should return

```
[1010101, 1, 1110101110111]
```

(it should take into regex sequences of zero which are divisible by 3, in this case 000 and 000000)

I tried with `split("[0{3}]+")` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Find the substring you need, get the index, split from there.

Comment: When you say multiples of 3, do you mean exactly 3, or at least 3?

Comment: can you explain the logic a bit more...

Comment: why do you have 1 then? if you need multiples of 3?

Comment: at least 3, then 6, 9, 12 etc. @musefan

Comment: @Joey: What if you have 4 zeros? So for example, `11000100001`... what would output be?

Comment: in this case it will split around 000 only: [11, 100001] @musefan

Comment: @Joey: Update your question with that information, as I think people who are answering are confused with your requirements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `split("(0{3})+")` should solve it. Putting something between `[]` means that you are trying to look for certain characters that is in that block.

**UPDATE**

If we want what is desired in the comments it should be like this:
`split("(?<!0)(0{3})+(?!(0{1,2}))")`. It is a bit more complex, but it should give the desired output.

So lets say we have `100001` as input. The part `(?<!0)` will make sure there is never a `0` at the beginning, otherwise results may look like `[10, 1]`. And `(?!(0{1,2}))` checks if there are 1 or 2 remaining `0`.

This will give `[100001]` with the given input. With input `1000100001` it will result in `[1, 100001]`

Comment: I believe the OP wants to split **only** if the number of zeros is a multiple of 3. So if there are 4 zeros then it should not split, but 3, 6, 9, etc. should split

Comment: @musefan I updated my anser. From what I can read this should be the desired solution

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String str = "101010100010000001110101110111";
String[] strArray = str.split("(0{3})+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "101010100010000001110101110111";

        for (String el : s.split("(0{3})+")) {
            System.out.println(el);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **regular expressions** for splitting Strings.

It is a very powerful tool. Almost a language itself.

**In your case**:

**s.split("0{3,}")**

See you.

David.